# Extract week number from POSIXct object

Tags: r, date, lubridate

Is there a function in `lubridate` to extract the week number?
I've tried to search for that but couldn't find anything which serves the purpose.

The `week()` function does something different.

> **Description**
>
> Date-time must be a POSIXct, POSIXlt, Date, chron, yearmon, yearqtr, zoo, zooreg, timeDate, xts, > its, ti, jul, timeSeries, and fts objects. Weeks is the number of complete seven day periods
> that have occured between the date and January 1st, plus one. isoweek returns the week as it
> would appear in the ISO 8601 system, which uses a reoccuring leap week.

Comment: Check `?strptime` (in base R) and then check `%W` or `%U`

Comment: What's the week number for you ? For example if the january 1st is Thursday, which week number do you expect on january 6th (Monday) ? Also, what's your input ? A datetime in string format ?

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ISOweek/ISOweek.pdf

Comment: In the help text you cite, the `lubridate` function `isoweek` is mentioned. If neither `week` or `isoweek` doesn't provide the answer, you need to clarify [**which week system**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-day_week#Week_numbering) you are looking for.

Answer (score 12):

Use `strftime`:

```
dateRange <- c("2008-10-01","2008-12-01") 
x <- as.POSIXlt(dateRange) 
strftime(x,format="%W") 
[1] "39" "48"
```