# Week Number Type in Google Trends

Tags: r, lubridate, week-number, google-trends

This is probably a very basic question
I have downloaded a Google trends file and the date range for each row is a week format similar to 2004-01-04 - 2004-01-10. This is basically Sun to Sat

Pseudo Code here where the Week is equal to the format above (2004-01-04 - 2004-01-10)

```
googledata <- googledata %>%
  mutate(startdate = ymd(substr(Week, 1, 10)),
     enddate = ymd(substr(Week, 14, 26)),
     weekno = isoweek(startdate),
     weekno2 = isoweek(enddate))
```

Sample Data

```
Week                    Vol
2004-01-04 - 2004-01-10 15
2004-01-11 - 2004-01-17 12
2004-01-18 - 2004-01-24 10
2004-01-25 - 2004-01-31 10
2004-02-01 - 2004-02-07 9
2004-02-08 - 2004-02-14 9
```

I have two questions

Is this a specific week type for example ISO. 
Is it possible to convert it to a week number using `lubridate` or some other function in R. The problem is using `isoweek` and `week` result in split weeks for the start and end date

I have a second data set i want to match up but it uses a different Week Number type, so i would like to convert them both to the Google type

Thank you for your help

Comment: `as.yearmon()` and then specifying what you want (e.g. month (`%b`) or year (`%Y`) , etc...) should do what you want.

Comment: Hi @Edu, thanks for the feedback but im not sure i follow. I need it on the as a week number

Comment: It would be good if you can provide a sample of your data...

Answer (score 0):

This is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866436/extract-week-number-from-posixct-object.)

You have to transform your date into `POSIXlt` object and then apply `strftime` specifying the week `%W` argument. In your sample I would create two different variables corresponding the initial date and final date for each week. It may be easier for manipulations.

```
    Initial      Final
1 04/01/2004 10/01/2004
2 11/01/2004 17/01/2004
3 18/01/2004 24/01/2004
4 25/01/2004 31/01/2004
5 01/02/2004 07/02/2004
6 08/02/2004 14/02/2004
```

Another alternative could be to create a variable with the number of weeks (`example$n_week =  rep(1:6)`)

Comment: Hi @Edu, I saw and tried this but the problem is that google trends week is count Sun to Sat as a week. So when i use this method it doesnt give me a whole week. The start date is in the first week and the end date is in the next week