# How to aggregate minute-based data to weekly data

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I've got data like this:

```
        Date     Time Global_active_power
1 16/12/2006 17:24:00               4.216
2 16/12/2006 17:25:00               5.360
3 16/12/2006 17:26:00               5.374
4 16/12/2006 17:27:00               5.388
5 16/12/2006 17:28:00               3.666
6 16/12/2006 17:29:00               3.520
```

Since I need to conduct a time-series analysis, I may need to aggregate these minutes-based data to daily-based, weekly-based, monthly-based, or quarter-based data. However, I've tried to use to following code to get monthly- and quarter-based data (based on function `as.yearmon` and `as.yearqtr`):

```
agg_Month <-aggregate(tmp_hPower,by=list(as.yearmon(tmp_hPower$Date,'%d/%m/%Y')), 
FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE )
```

It seems that there is no function like `as.yearweek`, so how can I obtain daily-based, weekly-based data, and even hour-based data?

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866436/extract-week-number-from-posixct-object).

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly simple if you convert your data.frame to an xts object.

```
# original data
tmp_hPower <- read.table(text="        Date     Time Global_active_power
1 16/12/2006 17:24:00               4.216
2 16/12/2006 17:25:00               5.360
3 16/12/2006 17:26:00               5.374
4 16/12/2006 17:27:00               5.388
5 16/12/2006 17:28:00               3.666
6 16/12/2006 17:29:00               3.520")
# xts object from original data
library(xts)
x <- with(tmp_hPower, xts(Global_active_power,
  as.POSIXct(paste(Date,Time), format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")))
# use period.apply and endpoints to aggregate to any frequency
period.apply(x, endpoints(x, "hours"), mean)  # hourly
period.apply(x, endpoints(x, "days"), mean)   # daily
period.apply(x, endpoints(x, "weeks"), mean)  # weekly
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)

# Fake data
set.seed(4999)
dat = data.frame(time=seq(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01"),
                          as.POSIXct("2016-12-31"), length.out=1000),
                 value=rnorm(1000))
```

You can add time groups that will allow you to summarize by week, month, etc.

```
dat = dat %>% 
  mutate(year_day = paste0(year(time),'-', yday(time)),
         year_week = paste0(year(time),"-",strftime(time,"%W")),
         year_mon = as.yearmon(time),
         year_qtr = as.yearqtr(time))
```

Now, summarise by week. You can summarize by day, month, etc., in a similar way.

```
dat.by.week = dat %>%
  group_by(year_week) %>%
  summarise(value=mean(value))
```

Also, you don't actually have to add the time groups to your original data. You can just do the whole thing on the fly. For example:

```
dat.by.week = dat %>% 
  mutate(year_week = paste0(year(time),"-",strftime(time,"%W"))) %>%
  group_by(year_week) %>%
  summarise(value=mean(value))
```